# LibreOffice auto-correction: lowercase i is corrected to uppercase (I) in other languages

Tags: language, libreoffice

I have to cross-post here a [question already posted on ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/ro/question/60798/how-to-avoid-english-auto-correction-in-other-languages/) because I don't have an answer to a small but nasty problem (I'll delete one of these questions when I get a satisfying answer in the other):

Although spell-check for Romanian is enabled and the auto-correct options should follow that spell-check language, what happens is that ***i*** is changed  automatically (auto-corrected) to ***I*** just like in English.  A such auto-correction is not present for Romanian. It is for US English.

[image]

[image]

If I want to write something like ***Ei i-au spus*** ("They told him"), when I write ***-*** after ***i*** the auto-correction produces ***I-*** (the same letter but uppercase) instead of ***i-*** and I get the incorrect if not biblical ***Ei I-au spus*** ('They told Him', as if 'they' were talking to God.) It is in fact the English auto-correction from ***i*** to ***I*** (like in ***I am***).

[image]

Also, **i** is changed to uppercase after clicking **space** after it (only that **i** alone is not a word in Romanian).

[image]

I have tested with different common fonts. It does not seem font-related.

Comment: should i delete the other one or not??

Comment: @cipricus No. Please don't. If you get an answer there you can write your own answer here.

Comment: @cipricus What do you have set for Tools > Language > For all text? Have you set it to Romanian. If I remember correctly it is this setting that determines which Autocorrect Language and Spell Check Language settings to use.

Comment: @cipricus Tools > Language > For all text > More, then set Default Languages for Documents to Romanian (check For the current document only) works here. See screenshot http://i.imgur.com/DrSF625.png I can add as many `i ` as I want ....

Comment: @DavidPostill - disregard my former comment now deleted. Please post your comment as answer as it works. I mean the image. Or I can do that if you prefer.

Comment: Answer posted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Lowercase i is corrected to uppercase (I) in other languages

You need to set the document language:

- Menu "Tools" > "Language" > "For all text" > "More" *or* Menu "Tools" > Options" > "Language Settings" > Language
- Set "Default Languages for Documents" to "Romanian"
- Optionally check "For the current document only"
- Click "OK"

[image]

---

If this still doesn't fix the problem completely and other terms are still wrongly changed to English, one can disable the use of replacement table under 'Tools-Auto-correct options/Options'.

Comment: After following your answer and fixing as you said now I can even roll back to English US for default language for documents and if I change a paragraph language to Romanian the problem is absent. Odd, like a small bug fixed by changing at least once the default language for documents

Comment: @cipricus It may well be a bug. I normally use only English so I've never had the problem. I'm glad you have it all working though ;)

Comment: very odd, I have to signal that if the mentioned change from 'i' to 'I' is gone by your solution I have now a different example of the same problem: *excelent* is changed to *excellent*. I simply have to disable replacement tables under 'Tools/Auto-correct options/Options'.

Comment: the initial and the second problem were both in version 4.7. they are gone in version 5.2. the main part of the answer should be: "Update!" :)